# NameError: name 'video_ad_' is not defined

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-2.7

```
video_ad_1 = {
    "title": "Healthy Living", 
    "company": "Health Promotion Board", 
    "views": 65423
}

video_ad_2 = {
    "title": "Get a ride, anytime anywhere", 
    "company": "GoJek", 
    "views": 54323
}

video_ad_view1=video_ad_1["views"]
print(video_ad_view1)

for i in range(1,2):
    print (i)
    video_ad_view[i] = video_ad_[i]["views"]
    print(video_ad_view[i])
```

How to do a loop to extract out the video views rather than having to do it one by one?

Output:

65423

This is the error I am getting:

```
NameError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-48-c03b13a08f2d> in <module>
      3 
      4 for i in range(1,5):
----> 5     video_ad_[i] = 0
      6     print (i)
      7     video_ad_view[i] = video_ad_[i]["views"]

NameError: name 'video_ad_' is not defined
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Best is you create a list of the dictionaries and iterate over that

```
video_ad_1 = {
    "title": "Healthy Living", 
    "company": "Health Promotion Board", 
    "views": 65423
}

video_ad_2 = {
    "title": "Get a ride, anytime anywhere", 
    "company": "GoJek", 
    "views": 54323
}

video_ads = [video_ad_1,video_ad_2]

video_ad_view1=video_ad_1["views"]
print(video_ad_view1)

for x in range(len(video_ads)):
    #print (i)
    video_ads[x] = video_ads[x]["views"]
    print(video_ads[x])
```